# Title under chart in amCharts

Tags: amcharts

I need to place title & subtitle under my chart in amCharts library. I tried to use label but I can only place a label in chart area. Anyone got an idea?

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titles can only be placed on the top of the chart. You can use labels to mimic the title functionality by using percent-based x/y coordinates, but you have to set your own margins as labels don't automatically shift the chart margins like titles do. You have to set [`autoMargins`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#autoMargins) to false and then set your own chart margins, especially [`marginBottom`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmSerialChart#marginBottom), in order to give your labels enough space to render on the bottom:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "autoMargins": false,
  "marginLeft": 50,
  "marginRight": 20,
  "marginBottom": 100,
  "allLabels": [{
    "x": "50%",
    "align": "middle",
    "y": "89%",
    "bold": true,
    "size": 16,
    "text": "My Chart Title"
  },{
    "x": "50%",
    "align": "middle",
    "y": "94%",
    "text": "My Chart Sub-Title"
  }],
// ...
});
```

Here's a [demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/e269166d2fc0992b26d9a55230b1ffc0?editors=0010)